# How to do static analysis for C++ code with Eclipse cdt?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, static-code-analysis

I need to get the static information of C++ program with CDT. No need to build the project, just to get the basic information(namespace, class, extends relation, method, call, field) and save them to database. Is there any code examples or opensource plugin? thx!

I have tried a lot of methods but they do not work very well. someone says that codan is a choice, but it doesn't work on my environment...

PS: CDT is necessary. I use Eclipse Indigo.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse CDT has already built-in tools for extends relation, method call. It is [Type Hierarchy view](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_type_hierarchy_view.htm) and [Call Hierarchy view](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_call_hierarchy_view.htm). You have to build Index of your project for all this tools to work.

Comment: This shows the views, but nothing about analyzing code like PC Lint, Covarity, Klocworks, etc.

Comment: I want to extract the information from code and store them into database. It is used for software reengineering

Comment: @Mark you can copy expanded hierarchy in view to clipboard, if this helps to do what you want.