# call graph for a single method (c++ and java)

Tags: java, c++, methods, hierarchy, call-graph

For a given method (eg. Settings.cpp getSettingByName()), I would like to build a static call graph. Is there an opensource tool that can do this for both java and c++?

For example, if I gave it "Settings.cpp getMethodByName" it would return:

```
Settings.cpp    getSettingByName();
    SettingsWrapper.cpp getMaximumSpeed();
        ECU.cpp monitorSpeed();
            Operate.cpp runECU();
                Main.cpp run();
        CruiseControl.cpp accelerate();
            Operate.cpp runCruiseControl();
                Main.cpp run();
        Radio.cpp playApplauseThroughSpeakers();
            Operate.cpp runStereo();
                Main.cpp run();
```

Don't freak about the code, it's just an example.

Many thanks,
Fidel

Comment: Haven't used this specific feature, but Doxygen? http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/config.html#cfg_call_graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) is an excellent tool that can do this for both Java and C++. It even generates graphical and clickable call graphs.

Comment: I didn't think Doxygen could correctly resolve overloaded symbols or methods from classes with multiple inheritance; it has a "hueristic" parser as a front end, not a real C++ front end.   For tiny programs, maybe Doxygen gives the right result.   Do you have specific experience or understanding that it will give the right result for a complex application in which the real complexities of C++ are present?

Comment: @IraBaxter Yep, I have tried it on fairly large applications which more than 100K LOC. My colleagues have tried it on on a C++, C++/CLI, C# application which has more then 5M LOC and did not hear any complains from them

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse provides a "call hierarchy" view. This is available in both the Java and C/C++ IDE flavors. For the latter, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7325174/127035) to the question: *Could anyone tell me how to do static analysis for C++ code with Eclipse cdt?*

See also [Accessing Eclipse's call hierarchy programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9986870/127035).